# C# adding value/index to items in an array and keeping track in Console how often they have been clicked

Tags: c#

For an assignment I'm stuck on this part. I'm as beginner a beginner programmer can be.

So I have an array attached to a listbox. This is the declaration of the array:

```
        number = new decimal[5];
        number[0] = 0.10m;
        number[1] = 0.20m;
        number[2] = 0.30m;
        number[3] = 0.40m;  
        number[4] = 0.50m;
```

And this is how I attached the array to the listbox

```
        lstNumbers.Items.Add(number[0]);
        lstNumbers.Items.Add(number[1]);
        lstNumbers.Items.Add(number[2]);
        lstNumbers.Items.Add(number[3]);
        lstNumbers.Items.Add(number[4]);
```

Since it's a listbox, these items(/values?) will be clicked on. I need to give each number their own index. Number[0] is 0.10 so index should be 010. How should I do this?

Another problem I'm having trouble solving is this: Each time you click on any of these items, it's kept track in an array and in the console. Example, if you click 0.10 once, this appears in Console: "0.10, 1 time." Click 3 times, Console should say: "0.10, 1 time. 0.10, 2 times. 0.10, 3 times."

I was told an associative array could help, but I'm not sure how this should look like. Tried searching for it, but mostly it's for PHP and the few for C# go a bit too complicated.

Here's to hoping anyone is able to help me out a little.

Comment: What kind of listbox is it?  Winforms?  WPF?

Comment: Giving `number[0] ` an index of 010 is impossible. The first item in the list box has an index of 0, the second item has an index of 1 and so on.

Comment: Sorry, did not see the comments till now. Still new with the website. It's a WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok lets start with the first. If you are using a windows form you can set the project to have a console output along with your windows form.

This is achieved by:

Right click your project -> Select Properties.Change the output type to Console Application.

[image]

How to have an array that uses string as index? Simple use a Dictionary.

```
       Dictionary<string, decimal> number = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

        number["010"] = 0.10m;
        number["020"] = 0.20m;
        number["030"] = 0.30m;
        number["040"] = 0.40m;
        number["050"] = 0.50m;

        this.myListBox.Items.Add(number["010"]);
        this.myListBox.Items.Add(number["020"]);
        this.myListBox.Items.Add(number["030"]);
        this.myListBox.Items.Add(number["040"]);
        this.myListBox.Items.Add(number["050"]);
```

Last point is very straight forward. Attach a SelectIndexChanged event to your listbox and keep track of the selected item:

```
    private void myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = this.myListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if(!tracking.Select(x=> x.Key == item).Any())
        {
            tracking.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(item, 1));
            Console.WriteLine(item + " has been selected once");
        }
        else
        {
            var currentItem = tracking.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == item);
            var value = currentItem.Value;
            tracking.Remove(currentItem);
            value++;
            tracking.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(item, value));
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(item + " has been selected " + value + " times");
        }
    }
```

The   variable tracking has been declared as following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> tracking = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dictionary<string, decimal> number = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

        number["010"] = 0.10m;
        number["020"] = 0.20m;
```

**EDIT**

As the dictionary cannot be used and also the application is WPF here is another solution.

Again you can use the first step showed to have a WPF solution with a console output:
Right click your project -> Select Properties.Change the output type to Console Application.

To have a collection that uses an object as an index is to use an Hashtable.

Here is your main:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> tracking = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Hashtable numbers = new Hashtable();

        numbers.Add("010", 0.10m);
        numbers.Add("020", 0.20m);
        numbers.Add("030", 0.30m);
        numbers.Add("040", 0.40m);
        numbers.Add("050", 0.50m);

        List<decimal> items = new List<decimal>();
        items.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(numbers["010"]));
        items.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(numbers["020"]));
        items.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(numbers["030"]));
        items.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(numbers["040"]));
        items.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(numbers["050"]));

        lbTodoList.ItemsSource = items;
    }

    private void lbTodoList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = this.lbTodoList.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (!tracking.Select(x => x.Key == item).Any())
        {
            tracking.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(item, 1));
            Console.WriteLine(item + " has been selected once");
        }
        else
        {
            var currentItem = tracking.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == item);
            var value = currentItem.Value;
            tracking.Remove(currentItem);
            value++;
            tracking.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(item, value));
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(item + " has been selected " + value + " times");
        }
    }
}
```

Your XAML should be as simple as:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox  Name="lbTodoList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="154" Margin="145,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="277" SelectionChanged="lbTodoList_SelectionChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

Remeber to Attach a SelectIndexChanged event to your listbox and keep track of the selected item.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's a .wpf file. As for dictionary, we've seen it but the lector told us that dictionary (and switches) are not necessary for the program. I don't know if there's an alternative?

Comment: what about a List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> ? can you use that?

Comment: That should be possible.

Comment: I think here you need an hashtable :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help so far, I'm getting closer to completing my assignment. Nice since it's due to midnight today.

Got a (hopefully final) question.

So I got two listboxes right now. ListBox 1 has an enum attached. In this enum are items that have a value (different for each item). We also have the second listbox where these numbers appear in. What I'm trying to figure out:

Item1 from Listbox1 has a value of 1.70. If you click 0.50 in Listbox2 4 times, then the total value should be 2.00. When the value of the numbers is equal or greater then the value of Listbox1, a message will appear in a label and if you went over the value of Listbox1, then it will also say how many of the other numbers (in this case, 1 of 0.10 and 1 of 0.20) will be returned.

PS: Those numbers are actually coins and I'm trying to code a distribution machine (so the items are food/drinks) but I changed stuff a little to make sure I could learn from the given answers.

Comment: I am glad I have been of some help. As this is another question you should really make another post. Also it would be nice if you can accept my answer.

Comment: Accepted it! And I'll make another post, thanks for the suggestion.