# C# Listboxes and values for a vending machine

Tags: c#, arrays, enums, listbox

This post is less or more linked to my previous post: [C# adding value/index to items in an array and keeping track in Console how often they have been clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460411/c-sharp-adding-value-index-to-items-in-an-array-and-keeping-track-in-console-how)

I'm not sure how to word my title, sorry for any confusion. My assignment is coding a basic vending machine.

So I got two listboxes right now. ListBox 1 has an enum attached. In this enum are 4 items that have a price for each item. Item1 has a price of 1.7 euros (index in enum is 170), Item2 is priced at 2 euros (index in enum is 200) and so forth. I have coded this already.

When selecting one of these items, ListBox2 appears. This contain the coins that you can click on to pay for the selected item. Coins are 0.10, 0.20, 0.30, 0.50, 1.00 and 2.00. I coded these listboxes and their enum/array already.

What I'm supposed to do (and struggling to do) is creating an array (I think so at least) that counts every time I click on any of these coins. If I selected Item1, which is priced at 1.70 euros (so index is 170), then if I click 0.50 4 times, this will come out at 2.00 (index of 200) which means the value of Item1 has been met. A label will appear to mention the value has been met and will also show how many coins (and how many of each coin) has been selected.

Additionally, if the value of the coins is greater then the value of the selected item, then additional lines will appear how many of each coin you'll get returned. In this case, it should say 1 of 0.10 and 1 of 0.20.

I can't figure out for the life of it how to tackle this problem. I'm a total beginner at programming and this is for an assignment that's due to tonight.

I hope anyone could help me out with this.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is for a .wpf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have helped you on the previous post I thought I would help you here too. This was simple once you understand the logic. I have written and app that does what is required. It might need some tidy up, but it is fully operational.

Here is your main:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> tracking = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> changeGiven = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        List<decimal> coinItems = new List<decimal>();

        decimal valueSelected;
        decimal coinSoFar = 0;
        Hashtable coins = new Hashtable();
        Hashtable prices = new Hashtable();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            coins.Add("010", 0.10m);
            coins.Add("020", 0.20m);
            coins.Add("030", 0.30m);
            coins.Add("040", 0.40m);
            coins.Add("050", 0.50m);

            coinItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(coins["010"]));
            coinItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(coins["020"]));
            coinItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(coins["030"]));
            coinItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(coins["040"]));
            coinItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(coins["050"]));

            lbTodoList.ItemsSource = coinItems;

            prices.Add("100", 1.10m);
            prices.Add("120", 1.20m);
            prices.Add("130", 1.30m);
            prices.Add("140", 1.40m);
            prices.Add("150", 1.50m);
            prices.Add("160", 1.60m);
            prices.Add("170", 1.70m);

            List<decimal> priceItems = new List<decimal>();
            priceItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(prices["100"]));
            priceItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(prices["120"]));
            priceItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(prices["130"]));
            priceItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(prices["140"]));
            priceItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(prices["150"]));
            priceItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(prices["160"]));
            priceItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(prices["170"]));

            lbPrice.ItemsSource = priceItems;
        }

        private void lbTodoList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = this.lbTodoList.SelectedItem?.ToString();
            if (item != null)
            {
                if (!tracking.Select(x => x.Key == item).Any())
                {
                    tracking.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(item, 1));
                    Console.WriteLine(item + " has been selected once");
                }
                else
                {
                    var currentItem = tracking.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == item);
                    var value = currentItem.Value;
                    tracking.Remove(currentItem);
                    value++;
                    tracking.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(item, value));
                }

                var getIndex = item.Replace(".", "");
                coinSoFar += Convert.ToDecimal(coins[getIndex]);

                if (coinSoFar >= valueSelected)
                {
                    StringBuilder coinsInserted = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var coinTracked in tracking)
                    {
                        coinsInserted.Append(coinTracked.Key + " x " + coinTracked.Value + "; ");
                    }

                    var difference = coinSoFar - valueSelected;

                    int coinDifferenceIndex = 0;
                    StringBuilder coinsReturned = new StringBuilder();
                    while (difference != 0)
                    {
                        var currentCoin = coinItems[coinDifferenceIndex];
                        difference -= currentCoin;

                        var currentItem = changeGiven.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == currentCoin.ToString());
                        if (currentItem.Key != null)
                        {
                            var value = currentItem.Value;
                            changeGiven.Remove(currentItem);
                            value++;
                            changeGiven.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(currentItem.Key, value));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            changeGiven.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(currentCoin.ToString(), 1));
                        }

                        if (difference > currentCoin)
                        {
                            coinDifferenceIndex++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            coinDifferenceIndex = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var coin in changeGiven)
                    {
                        coinsReturned.Append(coin.Key + " x " + coin.Value + "; ");
                    }

                    if(changeGiven.Any())
                    {
                        this.lblEnoughMoneyReached.Content = "Cost value has been met. Coins inserted: " + coinsInserted + ".Change given: " + coinsReturned;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.lblEnoughMoneyReached.Content = "Cost value has been met. Coins inserted: " + coinsInserted;
                    }  
                }
            }
            this.lbTodoList.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        private void lbPrice_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            valueSelected = Convert.ToDecimal(this.lbPrice.SelectedItem?.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And your XAML should look like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="lbTodoList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="154" Margin="145,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="277" SelectionChanged="lbTodoList_SelectionChanged">
        </ListBox>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="lbPrice" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="154" Margin="525,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="277" SelectionChanged="lbPrice_SelectionChanged">
        </ListBox>

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="lblEnoughMoneyReached" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="154" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Label>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks! So much closer to my goal now.

Comment: We don't recommend that you use the Hashtable class for new development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic Dictionary<TKey,TValue> class. For more information, see Non-generic collections shouldn't be used on GitHub. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0006.md